# Display a "currently unavailable" video/image when Livestream is down in Flowplayer

Tags: flowplayer, rtmp

How can you tell when [**Flowplayer**](http://flowplayer.org/) has crashed with an error when [**Livestream**](http://new.livestream.com/) breaks due to encoder crash, loss of internet stream, or other technical difficulties?

What I would like to do is display a video telling viewers what steps to take in order to get **Livestream** back or perhaps display a "***We are sorry***" image.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with http-live-streaming? It seems more likely that you mean RTMP.

Comment: i changed it, but HDS is a form of HTTP live streaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**Flowplayer Configuration Page**](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/player.html#playerevents) shows a **Player Event Listener** named [**onError**](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/configuration/player.html#playerevents) that's useful:

[image]
[image]

**Practical Example:**
Whenever the `onError Player Event Listener` is invoked, it will fire your function. Then, you can test via `if statements` or if many codes are needed use `switch-case conditional` to see what error was triggered **and take the appropriate action** from there (e.g., different rules depending on what error code was detected can be done).

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630804/1195891) example of using `FlowPlayer onError Player Event Listener` for error `200`:

```
onError: function(errorCode, errorMessage) {
    this.unload();
    switch (errorCode) {
        case 200:
            $('#myPlayer a').attr('src', StreamNotFound.jpg);
        break;
    }
}
```

**The Delivery:**
If you already have a multimedia **lightbox type script** on the website, you can take advantage of that to trigger an **image**, **video**, **HTML webpage** via iframe, etc. to relay any directions to the viewer instead of the `.jpg` image method above. Many lightbox scripts have *callback options* and that can be used to log the successful delivery of error messages (logged via AJAX post for example) to take this "***damage-control***" even further.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if i didn't saw your answer earlyer.